# Select multiple items in <ice:selectOneMenu> component

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

I would like to know if it is possible to select multiple items in  `<ice:selectOneMenu>` component, or is there any other component in Icefaces which allows a user to select multiple values from a list.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ice:selectManyMenu](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/compat/comps/tld/ice/selectManyMenu.html)

```
<ice:selectManyMenu value="#{bean.selectedValues}" >
<f:selectItem itemValue="Value1" itemLabel="Value1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Value2" itemLabel="Value2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Value3" itemLabel="Value3" />
</ice:selectManyMenu>
```